# Unable to find the default constructor on type ClassName. Please provide the missing constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I try to manage Firebase Authentification into a custom class where everything about Authentification will be done. First I try to create an instance of this in the MainActivity.cs by calling

```
AuthService.GetInstance();
```

But it crash on runtime with this error :

> Unable to find the default constructor on type AuthService.  Please provide the missing constructor.

Here is my class AuthService which I try to initialise my singleton. What is wrong with this constructor ? Is this because my class inherit of Java.Lang.Object and singleton won't work as it always worked before ?

```
public class AuthService : Java.Lang.Object, 
                            IOnSuccessListener, 
                            IOnFailureListener
{
    public User CurrentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    private static AuthService _instance = null;
    private static System.Object _mutex = new object();

    public IntPtr Handle {get;}

    public static AuthService GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (_mutex) // now I can claim some form of thread safety...
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new AuthService();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private AuthService()
    {
       Initialise();
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        this.firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;

        if (FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            this.CurrentUser = User.GetInstance();
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly implement the singleton pattern, you must avoid making your constructor public. Therefore, you should avoid Java.Lang.Object which seems to force you to have a public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your *Default Constructor* is `private` (which is all sorts of curious), make it `public`

```
public AuthService()
{
   ...
```

[Private Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors)

> A private constructor is a special instance constructor. It is
>   generally used in classes that contain static members only. **If a class
>   has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other
>   classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class**.

Comment: omg! I made it public as you said and it worked.. But how can I be sure to always talk to the single instance Singleton ? I always did my singleton like the code above and talk to the instance by typing MyClass.GetInstance().WantedMethod(). I will read a little bite more...

Comment: You usually let your *DI container* take care of creating a single instance and assuring the consistency

Comment: Also you could probably replace the `_mutex` with a` new Object()`

Comment: the inheritance of Java.Lang.Object forces me to put the constructor public.. and it's completly not what I want.. so i will manage this class diffrently without all the interface and inheritance.